# A non well formed numeric value encountered - Error in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to multiply two values in php which gives me the error
**A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Code:

```
$value = 2.5/100;
$totalvalue = $value * $totalvalue;
echo $totalvalue;
```

Comment: Where do you have defined `$totalvalue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below :-

```
$totalvalue = 1.0 ; //Set $totalvalue and typecast to float

$value = 0.0 ;

$value = 2.5/100;

$totalvalue = $value * $totalvalue;

echo "<br>".$totalvalue;
```

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to typecast.

```
$value = 2.5/100;
$totalvalue = $value * (float)$totalvalue;
echo $totalvalue;
```