# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in php time script

Tags: php, datetime

I am generating drop down list to show 15 minutes duration  till 6 hrs it will generate like 15 minutes ,30 minutes,45 minutes but I am getting error non numeric value encountered so I followed below links but It didn't solved my issue

links Refer:

[date() method, "A non well formed numeric value encountered" does not want to format a date passed in $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574465/date-method-a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-does-not-want-to-fo)

[A non well formed numeric value encountered - Error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003775/a-non-well-formed-numeric-value-encountered-error-in-php)

```
<?php 

echo "<select>";

for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++){
    for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j +=15){
        if ($i === 0 && $j === 0){
            //do nothing
        }
        else{
            //get string for hours
            switch($i){
                case 0:
                    $hours = "";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $hours = "1 hour";
                    break;
                default:
                    $hours = $i . " hours";
                    break;
            }

            //get string for minutes
            switch($j){
                case 0:
                    $minutes = "";
                    break;
                default:
                    $minutes = $j . " minutes";
                    break;
            }

            $value = ($hours * 60) + $minutes;



            //output
            echo "<option value='" . $value . "'>" . $hours . " " . $minutes . "</option>";
        }
    }
}

echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: You are setting strings and then trying to do multiplication. For example `$hours = "1 hour";` -- cannot be multiplied by 60.

Comment: @Jeremy Harris what changes should I made

Comment: Don't try to multiply "1 hour" by 60. Change your code to only handle numbers in your loops, and then worry about how to display it AFTER you calculate.

Answer (score 2):

It was mistake which I did in code as suggested by @Jeremy Harris

[`Intval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) solved my issue

```
$value = (intval($hours) * 60) + intval($minutes);
```